# I need to sum the value of select box value inside jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I need to sum the select box value inside loop in jquery ,

```
     <?php 

for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) 
{
?>
<select class="sum-selector" id="options_<?php echo $i ?>">

   <option value="25">RS 25</option>
    <option value="30">Rs 30</option>
    <option value="45">Rs 45</option>
     <option value="95">Rs 95</option>
 </select>

 <?php  } ?>

<p id="sum_of_select"> </p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('.sum-selector').change(getSum);
function getSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.sum-selector').each(function(select) {
    if(select.value) {
      sum += parseInt(select.value);
      alert (sum)
    }
  });

  alert('sum is: ' + sum);
}
</script>
```

Here on  change the value is coming as 0 on alert i need to get the sum value of the three select box value , for example in first select box if i select 25 second 30 third 45 the output should be 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get the selected value

```
$('.sum-selector').each(function(i) {
     alert($(this).find('option:selected').val());
});
```

Here is your code :

```
<?php 

for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) 
{
?>
<select class="sum-selector" id="options_<?php echo $i; ?>">
     <option value="25">RS 25</option>
     <option value="30">Rs 30</option>
     <option value="45">Rs 45</option>
     <option value="95">Rs 95</option>
 </select>
<?php  } ?>

<p id="sum_of_select"> </p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('.sum-selector').change(getSum);
function getSum() 
{
  var sum = 0;
  $('.sum-selector').each(function(i) {
    if($(this).find('option:selected').val()) {
      sum += parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').val());
      alert(sum)
    }
  });
  alert('sum is: ' + sum);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g289yq5/), check online and let me know.

```
$(function(){
    $('.sum-selector').on("change", function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('.sum-selector option:selected').each(function(){
      var val = $(this).val();
      sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(val);
    });  
    $("#sum_of_select").text(sum);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .each method on the selector like you did in your example. You can select all the select boxes by class. Then loop through them and get the vaule by using the `this` keyword which references the element it is up to in the loop. Then get the value using `.val()` and add it to the sum

```
sum = 0;
$('select.sum-selector').each(function() {
    sum += $(this).val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#select').change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(this).find('option').each(function(index, element) {//find all option
    total += parseFloat(element.value) || 0;//get value of each option and add them
  });
  console.log(total)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sum-selector" id="select">

  <option value="25">RS 25</option>
  <option value="30">Rs 30</option>
  <option value="45">Rs 45</option>
  <option value="95">Rs 95</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Pure javascript without using JQuery

```
 <?php 

for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) 
{
?>
<select class="sum-selector" id="options_<?php echo $i ?>" onchange="newval('options_<?php echo $i ?>')">

   <option value="25">RS 25</option>
    <option value="30">Rs 30</option>
    <option value="45">Rs 45</option>
     <option value="95">Rs 95</option>
 </select>

 <?php  } ?>

<p id="sum_of_select"> </p>

<script>
function newval(options) {
 var val = document.getElementById(options);
 val.value =    parseInt(val.options[val.selectedIndex].value);
 sum();
}
function sum(){
sum =0;
for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
    var val = document.getElementById("options_"+i);
    var sum = sum + parseInt(val.options[val.selectedIndex].value);
}
console.log(sum);
}
</script>
```